# pandas merge with duplicate values in index

Tags: python, pandas

Hello,

I have the following two dataframes (df1, df2) and if I merge them (inner join), I get the following dataframe:

```
In [85]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'value' : [10, 11, 14, 16]}, index=[1, 2, 3, 3]); df1                 
Out[85]:             
   value             
1     10             
2     11             
3     14             
3     16             

In [86]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'value' : [11, 15, 16]}, index=[1, 3, 3]); df2                        
Out[86]:             
   value             
1     11             
3     15             
3     16             

In [87]: pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)                        
Out[87]:             
   value_x  value_y  
1       10       11  
3       14       15  
3       14       16  
3       16       15  
3       16       16
```

Instead of this, I would like to have the following dataframe

```
    value_x  value_y 
1     10      11     
3     14      15     
3     16      16
```

Basically in case of duplicate rows, do not do `m * n` merging the way it it is currently happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need a new para here `key` , get by using `groupby` + `cumcount`

```
pd.merge(df1.assign(key=df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount()).reset_index(),
    df2.assign(key=df2.groupby(level=0).cumcount()).reset_index(),
         how='inner',on=['index','key']).\
             drop('key',1).set_index('index')
Out[25]: 
       value_x  value_y
index                  
1           10       11
3           14       15
3           16       16
```